# Webview crashed on playing flash swf android 4.2.2

Tags: flash, webview, android-webview

i have installed adobe flashplayer 11.1 on my device , flash content is working fine in webview, but its getting crash randomly after few minutes, In error log i got this stacktrace

```
09-27 14:41:00.490 E/[Gralloc-3X-ERROR](15117): int gralloc_register_buffer(const gralloc_module_t*, buffer_handle_t):135 Failed to create UMP handle 0x0
09-27 14:41:00.490 W/GraphicBufferMapper(15117): registerBuffer(0x854f2b60) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
09-27 14:41:00.490 E/GraphicBuffer(15117): unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Invalid argument (-22)
09-27 14:41:00.620 D/Jian    (15117): DrawIconOnNativeWindow has Invert 
09-27 14:41:00.620 E/SurfaceTextureClient(15117): Surface::lock failed, already locked
09-27 14:41:00.630 D/Jian    (15117): DrawIconOnNativeWindow has Invert 
09-27 14:41:00.630 E/[Gralloc-3X-ERROR](15117): int gralloc_register_buffer(const gralloc_module_t*, buffer_handle_t):135 Failed to create UMP handle 0x0
09-27 14:41:00.640 W/GraphicBufferMapper(15117): registerBuffer(0x79006520) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
09-27 14:41:00.640 E/GraphicBuffer(15117): unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Invalid argument (-22)
09-27 14:41:00.640 F/libc    (15117): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x4855a000 (code=2), thread 15146 (FP_DoPlay)
```

Is that any way to avoid this crash point or something else to handle this issue

Comment: Does it crash after a few minutes with _any Flash content in the world_ or just this one SWF? If it's _any Flash_ then probably a bad install procedure (was Flash force installed via some modding?). Or else you need to fix the code in your SWF. You didnt even say what it does or how it works (might be too heavy for a phone processor?)